# .htaccess why is it not redirecting?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

If I understand it right, it should:

Do nothing if a file with size or symbolic link is founded,
Redirect to `index.php` in any other case.

If I open `www.mysite.com/folder/` I get the `index.php`

If I open `www.mysite.com/folder/file.php` I get the `file.php`

If I open `www.mysite.com/test` which is not a `folder` neither a `file` I get the `404 error`, but I should get the `index.php`. Where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just turn it around to keep it more simple?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This should rewrite all files (With content) and symlinks to index.php and do nothing with anything else.
Less lines, less confusion..

Comment: Thank you, I need the opposite. So, instead of `-s -l`, is `!-s !-l` the right solution?
Still a question: why with your solution, if I point direct to I file (e.g. `www.mysite.com/folder/test.php`) I get this file, and not `index.php`?

Comment: So if its not a file with content AND not a symlink you want to redirect to index.php? In that case, yes.

Comment: Yes, I this file has content and is a symlink then I want this file, otherwise index.php. I edited my previous comment

Comment: I see you are a new user, so: Please accept this answer if it answered your question. Do this by clicking the check mark left of the question.

Comment: Sorry I was afk. I accepted the answer now! Can you please answer me why with your solution, if I point direct to I file (e.g. `www.mysite.com/folder/test.php`) I get this file, and not `index.php`?

Comment: You changed it to `!-s` and `!-l` right? Basically saying if its NOT a file with content and NOT a symlink, it has to go to index.php. Since test.php is probably a file with content, it wont go to index.php.

Comment: Yes. But with YOUR solution (so `-s -l`), when I was opening a file with size, I wasn't redirect to `index.php`. It seems something isn't working on your code, or maybe I'm not understanding it right!

Comment: Try adding the [OR], we were basically saying it should be a file with content -AND- a symlink, that wont ever happen.